# Quebra de linha no Excel (2013) via fórmula

Tags: microsoft-excel, quebras-de-linha

Como fazer quebra de linha na fórmula no Excel 2013 (acima)?

Constumava fazer desta forma:

```
="linha1"&CARACT(13)&CARACT(10)&"linha2"
```

Resultado atual:

```
linha1linha2
```

Resultado esperado:

```
linha1
linha2
```

Teoricamente somente o `CARACT(10)` já representa um `vbNewLine`, mas sempre tive de usar o `CARACT(13)` junto para funcionar.

Contudo, na versão mais atual do Excel, não estou conseguindo visualizar a quebra de linha.

Alguém poderia ajudar?

Comment: Na célula correspondente a formula clique com o botão direito do mouse vai na opção `Format Cells` aba `Alignment` e no `Text control` marque a caixa `Wrap text`. Desta forma o comando `CARACT(10)` vai funcionar.

Comment: Excelente! Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estava com o mesmo problema e cheguei até aqui. Encontrei a solução abaixo:
A formula ="linha1"&CARACT(10)&"linha2" esta correta. Precisa apenas formatar célula para quebrar texto automaticamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Observação:** Não foi necessário utilizar CARACT(13).

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Se você fizer um

```
=concatenar(A1;"
";A2)
```

ou

```
=A1&"
"&A2
```

Escrevento o comando com quebra de linha entre `""`, você terá o resultado esperado. Para quebrar a linha na fórmula basta usar <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score -2):

Não sei se ainda pode ajudar alguém, mas sem o uso de fórmula, é possível usar o <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> para inserir quebras de linhas.

Espero que ajude.